# spl_autoload_register() syntax/structure name

Tags: php, spl

I've used this function before but today while reusing it again, it came to my attention its structure. It's very similar to jQuery.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    // Todo
});
```

It looks like dependency injection but a function is being passed so it would not be dependency injection. Is there a name for it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called closures or anonymous functions, an inline function essentially.

[Anonymous Functions PHP](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer by David Farthing